# Why aren't my angular controller's dependencies in scope inside one of its methods?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a controller defined like so

```
var controller = function ($scope, dep1, dep2) {
  this.someFunction = function () {
    debugger;
    dep1.method();
  };
};

return ['$scope', 'dep1', 'dep2', controller];
```

when I hit the breakpoint in `someFunction` I only have reference to dep1 but not scope or dep2 inside the method's scope. If I were to add a line inside of `someFunction` using dep2 then it is added to the method's scope.

Why does this work this way? I would expect scope, dep1, and dep2 to always be in scope inside any method regardless of whether it was used or not.

Comment: We need to see a bit more code. How are `dep1` and `dep2` dependencies defined? Also, is the code above in the body of a function that gets called like `myApp.controller('myCtrl', registerController())`? If not, how does the code above get accessed?

Comment: This isn't an angular issue, this is a JavaScript mechanic.  Variables declared outside a function are only actually instantiated in the scope of a function the first time they are accessed, not when they are passed in.  It's how closures work.

Answer (score 0):

In which file you define your dep1 and dep2? Are they in 2 files? And maybe you should change the order of those script files. And the files about dep1 and dep2 before the controller file.